# Dynamically assigning value to variables inside select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've simplified the example for brevity.

I have a query that takes the total of 'agreed' and 'completed' sales figures for each staff member, and then calculates 'red', 'amber' and 'green' values for those people based on an arbitrary figure. In this example, we'll say 1m = red, 1.25m = amber and 1.5m = green.

Currently, the 1m, 1.25m and 1.5m values are hard-coded in the stored procedure. The main code is as follows:

```
DECLARE @redtarget int = '1000000'
DECLARE @ambtarget int = '1249999'
DECLARE @gretarget int = '1500000'    

SELECT
         name
         ,staff_id
         ,potential_sales_total
         ,confirmed_sales_total
         ,target_confirmed_figure
         ,case 
              WHEN confirmed_sales_total < @redtarget THEN 'Red'
              WHEN confirmed_sales_total BETWEEN @redtarget AND @ambtarget THEN 'Amber'
              WHEN confirmed_sales_total >= @gretarget THEN 'Green'
         END AS "Level"
    
    FROM
         [Sales_Figures]
```

However, some staff have custom sales targets, and this value is also contained within Sales_Figures. There aren't many occasions where this field is populated, but when it is then the red, amber and green values need to shift to account for the new figures. The threshold for 'Red' is the target_confirmed_figure * 0.667, 'Amber' is target_confirmed_figure * 0.833, and 'Green' is simply target_confirmed_figure itself.

I'm very close to getting this to work myself, but I keep getting lost in it and would very much appreciate some pointers. I think it's to do with more parameters in the case statement, such as if target_confirmed_figure is NULL, but it seems to get complicated very quickly. I'm an enthusiastic amateur only! There is the odd question on SO that could be vaguely similar, but they seem different enough to be of little help here.

Thanks

Comment: For help with a query please post table DDL, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: FYI, your `DECLARE` statements aren't valid. You need an an assignment equals (`=`) after the data type if you want to assign the value in the same statement you `DECLARE` it.

Comment: @Larnu oops, sorry yes I didn't put the = in...

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft noted David, and thanks. I imagined that this would be a fairly simple thing for someone more experienced and talented, and wouldn't require that. The example is different to my actual data, and wanted to keep it simple to avoid unnecessary complications when the issue in question is what I am interested in. If everyone thinks this is impossible without sample data, then fair enough. I'm just after some general guidance on how it would be accomplished. Thanks again.

Comment: Seems like you're after a `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` here, if I am honest.

Comment: Re "this would be a fairly simple thing" - it most likely is, but having insufficient data we just wont guess about your data structure. And, like Larnu said - generic hint here is to use isnull() or coalesce() :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end - that may not be the most elegant method - I decided to create a union statement. One statement showing only the default targets and applying the red, amber and green targets to those people. The second one showing only where the ones with custom targets are, and applying the red, amber and green criteria based on that value instead:

```
SELECT
         name
         ,staff_id
         ,potential_sales_total
         ,confirmed_sales_total
         ,target_confirmed_figure
         ,case 
              WHEN confirmed_sales_total < (target_confirmed_figure * 0.667) THEN 'Red'
              WHEN confirmed_sales_total > target_confirmed_figure THEN 'Green'
              ELSE 'Amber'
         END AS "Level"
FROM
         [Sales_Figures]
WHERE ISNULL(target_confirmed_figure,'yes') = 'yes'

UNION

SELECT
             name
             ,staff_id
             ,potential_sales_total
             ,confirmed_sales_total
             ,target_confirmed_figure
             ,case 
                  WHEN confirmed_sales_total < @redtarget THEN 'Red'
                  WHEN confirmed_sales_total >= @gretarget THEN 'Green'
                  ELSE 'Amber'
             END AS "Level"
FROM
      [Sales_Figures]
WHERE ISNULL(target_confirmed_figure,'yes') <> 'yes'
```

This seems to have done the job, and I get output that shows both the default and custom target figures in one table.

Thanks to everyone who assisted!!

Answer (score 0):

With limited info on your table and desire results, I'm not sure this is exactly correct, but I think this will accomplish what you are trying to do

```
DECLARE @redtarget int = 1000000
    ,@ambtarget int = 1249999
    ,@gretarget int = 1500000    

SELECT
     name
    ,staff_id
    ,potential_sales_total
    ,confirmed_sales_total
    ,target_confirmed_figure
    ,C.* /*Showing numbers for reference*/
    ,case 
        WHEN confirmed_sales_total < C.RedTarget THEN 'Red'
        WHEN confirmed_sales_total BETWEEN C.RedTarget AND C.AmbTarget THEN 'Amber'
        /*Do you want to categorize values between AmbTarget and GreTarget?*/
        WHEN confirmed_sales_total >= C.GreTarget THEN 'Green'
    END AS "Level"
FROM [Sales_Figures] AS S
/*Uses value in column Sales_Figure, unless it's null, then uses variables from above*/
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT RedTarget = ISNULL(ROUND(target_confirmed_figure*0.667,0),@redtarget)
            ,AmbTarget = ISNULL(ROUND(target_confirmed_figure*0.833,0),@ambtarget)
            ,GreTarget = ISNULL(target_confirmed_figure,@gretarget)
) AS C
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, @stephan, and it's appreciated. I've put your solution in, and yes it gives me the It does nearly what I need it to do, but I can't quite figure out how to apply the C cross join only when it's needed. The query needs to be able to determine if the person has a custom target, and if so apply the red/amber/green calc to THAT figure, but otherwise show the default 1m, 1.25m and 1.5m. Your solution doesn't seem to do this?

Comment: I suppose I could do one focussing on the default targets where target_confirmed_figure is null, and then union that with one where the t_c_f isn't null?